# MongoDB $pull Query Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Guys I want to make a **unfollow** request with $pull qıery but it doesnt work. How to solve this?

Also this method works fine with `$push` query when I want to follow request user but it doesnt work with `$pull`.

**My app.js:**

```
app.post('/unfollow/:id', function(req, res){

  User.find(req.user
  
  ).exec(function(err, user){
  
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
    
    User.find({"username":req.params.id}, function(err, friend){
      
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    User.update(user,{$pull: { follow: friend}}, function(err){
      if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.send("Success")
    } 
    });
  });
  });
  });
```

This is my how user's follow look like:

```
{ follow:
   [ 5edfe8f3bfc9d677005d55ca,
     5edfe92fbfc9d677005d55cc,
     5ee2326cc7351c5bb0b75f1a ],
```

I will take friend id from this array.

And my user model(**Follow part**):

```
follow:[{
    type: ObjectId,
}]
```

If pull doesnt work can you suggest me queries or ways to do unfollow request.

Comment: Please help for a few weeks I have been working for this issue

Answer (score 0):

`User.find({ username: req.params.id }` would return a document but looks like you do store `ObjectId`s in `follow` field. I except changing  `$pull: { follow: friend }` to `$pull: { follow: friend._id }` should solve the problem.

Comment: But when I do console log friend._id it logs as a undefined

Comment: When I do console log friend it logs whole user(friend)

Comment: Okey I have solved this with $pullAll query. I dont know why but

Comment: Interesting. I don't see how pullAll can work where pull doesn't work.

Comment: I dont know why